Internal microphone not working in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
So I'm very new to using ubuntu and barely understand any of the technical stuff but I recently dual booted my ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. ROG Zephyrus G14 GA401II_GA401II with windows 11 and Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and I've been having a few issues for starters the microphone doesn't seem to work and in pulseaudo it is recognized as Family 17h/19h HD audio controller but when i use windows it works just fine. I would really appreciate the help and would love to ask more question to learn more about Linux. Thank you

It would be helpful to know how the microphone is connected. Is it 3.5 or Bluetooth or USB?
